# Ruby proc vs lambda in initialize()

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

I found out this morning that proc.new works in a class initialize method, but not lambda. Concretely, I mean:

```
class TestClass

  attr_reader :proc, :lambda

  def initialize
    @proc = Proc.new {puts "Hello from Proc"}
    @lambda = lambda {puts "Hello from lambda"}
  end

end

c = TestClass.new
c.proc.call
c.lambda.call
```

In the above case, the result will be:

```
Hello from Proc
test.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you have defined an `attr_accessor` called `lambda` is hiding the original `lambda` method that creates a block (so your code is effectively hiding Ruby's `lambda`). You need to name the attribute something else for it to work:

```
class TestClass

  attr_reader :proc, :_lambda

  def initialize
    @proc = Proc.new {puts "Hello from Proc"}
    @_lambda = lambda {puts "Hello from lambda"}
  end

end

c = TestClass.new
c.proc.call
c._lambda.call
```

Comment: Calling `Kernel.lambda` is another option.